# MergeStrategy Not Found

Tags: scala, sbt

I am new to Scala and I am trying to run sbt. 
My build.sbt looks like this

```
name := "myFile"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.0" %"provided"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.0" % "provided"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-mllib" % "2.4.0" % "provided"

libraryDependencies+="org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.4.0" % "provided"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % "1.6.3"

mergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case m if m.toLowerCase.endsWith("manifest.mf")          => MergeStrategy.discard
  case m if m.toLowerCase.matches("meta-inf.*\\.sf$")      => MergeStrategy.discard
  case "log4j.properties"                                  => MergeStrategy.discard
  case m if m.toLowerCase.startsWith("meta-inf/services/") => MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
  case "reference.conf"                                    => MergeStrategy.concat
  case _                                                   => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

However when I try to run the command "sbt" I am getting following error:

```
/home/myFolder/build.sbt:17: error: not found: value mergeStrategy
mergeStrategy in assembly := {
^
/home/myFolder/build.sbt:17: error: not found: value assembly
mergeStrategy in assembly := {
                 ^
/home/myFolder/build.sbt:18: error: not found: value MergeStrategy
  case m if m.toLowerCase.endsWith("manifest.mf")          => MergeStrategy.discard
                                                              ^
/home/myFolder/build.sbt:19: error: not found: value MergeStrategy
  case m if m.toLowerCase.matches("meta-inf.*\\.sf$")      => MergeStrategy.discard
                                                              ^
/home/myFolder/build.sbt:20: error: not found: value MergeStrategy
  case "log4j.properties"                                  => MergeStrategy.discard
                                                              ^
/home/myFolder/build.sbt:21: error: not found: value MergeStrategy
  case m if m.toLowerCase.startsWith("meta-inf/services/") => MergeStrategy.filterDistinctLines
                                                              ^
/home/myFolder/build.sbt:22: error: not found: value MergeStrategy
  case "reference.conf"                                    => MergeStrategy.concat
                                                              ^
/home/myFolder/build.sbt:23: error: not found: value MergeStrategy
  case _                                                   => MergeStrategy.first
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: As a verification, have you added sbt-assembly plugin in your plugins.sbt?

Comment: addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "x.y.z"). Replace x.y.z with your version

Comment: See https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#using-published-plugin for more info...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the sbt.assembly file in project.